# How to target element which is not hidden with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

My html is as follows :

```
{# Navigation for xs screens #}
<div class="small-screen-nav hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm col-xs-12" style="padding: 0;">
    <ol class="breadcrumb" style="padding: 0px 7.5px">
        <li><a href="#" id="make" class="active">Make</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="model">Model</a></li>            
    </ol>
</div>

{# Navigation for sm, md, lg screens #}
<div id="calculation-menu" class="col-lg-2 hidden-xs">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" id="make" class="list-group-item active">Make</a>
        <a href="#" id="model" class="list-group-item">Model</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my jquery is as follows :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#make').removeClass('active').html("Some text");
        $('#model').addClass('active');
    })
</script>
```

But the problem is that it targets the navigation which is hidden. If I'm on large screen, first navigation is hidden, but jquery doesn't target nav which is not hidden (second one), but it targets the one which is hidden (the first one).

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ensure Unique `id` Attributes**

Firstly, you need to consider renaming your existing `id` attributes [as they are guaranteed to be unique by definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), and thus can cause all sorts of issues when this isn't the case.

Consider using a `class` attribute or a `data-*` attribute to handle this instead (attributes approach demonstrated below) :

```
<!-- Mobile -->
<div class="small-screen-nav hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm col-xs-12" style="padding: 0;">
    <ol class="breadcrumb" style="padding: 0px 7.5px">
        <li><a href="#" class="active" data-make>Make</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-model>Model</a></li>            
    </ol>
</div>

<!-- Small, Medium, and Large -->
<div id="calculation-menu" class="col-lg-2 hidden-xs">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active" data-make>Make</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-model>Model</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could then use this as expected:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('[data-make]').removeClass('active').html("Some text");
        $('[data-model]').addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

**Consider The `:visible` Selector**

Secondly, if you really wanted to target only the element that was visible, you could consider using the [`:visible` selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) in jQuery to handle this :

```
// This will only target the element with the data-make attribute that is currently visible
$('[data-make]:visible')
```

Answer (score 1):

Having duplicate id's is a bad idea all around, but if you really need a quick fix to target both elements, use the attribute selector:

so instead of `$('#make')`, use `$('[id="make"]')`.